# Textbox become non-editable after applying drag and drop property to it(dojo/dnd/Source)

Tags: dojo, drag-and-drop

I have created multiple text boxes and i have placed them in a div and made that div as source like this,

```
new dojo.dnd.Source(this.someAttachPoint);
```

If i do this i can do drag and drop but text box become non-eitable, How to make it editable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set parameter **skipForm** to **true** something like this.

```
new dojo.dnd.Source(this.someAttachPoint, { skipForm : true })
```

Refer [this](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dnd.html) for more help.